# Changing the price of a Membership in a Price Set does not transfer to a Webform

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, price-sets

I am using CiviCRM 5.13.4 and Drupal Webform 7.x-4.20.

I am using the Webform to collect payments for Membership.  The price of the available Membership Types is set up using a Price Set, which is called up by a Contribution Page, which itself is called up by the Webform.

When I change the price in the Price Set the amount charged by the Webform does not alter.  If I open the Contribution Page directly in CiviCRM (as a test) it shows the new price, but the Webform still shows the old one.

I wish to retain the price setting in a single place, to avoid possible operational problems and inconsistencies, and the Price Set seems to logical way to do this.  It there some other action needed to make it take effect, or is this a bug?

With thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Webform is not picking the price up from the Price Set at all, but from the 'Minimum Fee' field of the Membership Type record.  Even if the Minimum Fee is blank (NULL in the database) the Webform picks up zero rather than going to the Price Set.  (I had forgotten that the Minimum Fee was set (or even existed)).

In fact, not clear why I need Price Sets at all - will save a level of complexity if I can do away with them.

Tony

Comment: Exactly! With Webform CiviCRM you can add-on a Contribution with additional line items which will give you a Contribution with line items (like a priceset does - but you build it as you need it on the webform) -> so buy a Membership, make.a Donation and buy a calendar all on the same form.

Comment: Hi KarinG,   Could you point me at any description of just how to do that?

Comment: I have worked through that, and now don't have a (user generated) Price set at all.  Much easier.  Tony

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the 'Membership Fee' field to the webform under the memberships section?

Believe this will stop prices from being pulled from Civi.

Otherwise should pull across automatically as far as I am aware.

Comment: No, the 'Membership Fee' field is not selected.  But as described above the price picked up on the Payments page has not been pulled across.